# Deserialize Dynamic JSON file C# NewtonSoft.JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Working on deserializing a dynamic JSON file which could contain 2 separate classes and I won't know which type of data will be in the array.

The problem is, I deserialize the root object to type "Base", "subtests" objects are deserialized to "Subtest", but the "subtests" array could be of type "Base" or of type "Subtest".

**QUESTION:
How would I go about programatically determining that if the object contains "subtest", I deserialize to Base, and if it doesn't, it should deserialize to "Subtest"?**

I really appreciate the help on this one since I'm on a short timeline.

(EDIT: Added comments to show what type each object should deserialize to)
Here's an example (JSON DATA):

```
{
// Deserializes to type "Base"
  "host": "123456",
  "last_time": "2014-09-15 07:04:49.205000",
  "name": "myName",
  "result": "FAIL",
  "serial": "12345",
  "start_time": "2014-09-15 06:53:36.976000",
// Deserializes to type "List<Subtest>"
  "subtests": [
    {
      "data": {
        "moredata": {
          "ver": "123",
          "real": 123
        }
      },
      "description": "Description of Data",
      "host": "123456",
      "last_time": "2014-09-15 20:32:31.095000",
      "name": "testname.py",
      "result": "PASS",
      "start_time": "2014-09-15 20:32:25.873000",
      "version": "2.014.09.15"
    },
    {
// Nested within Subtest Array, Should deserialize to type "Base" again
      "host": "123456",
      "last_time": "2014-09-15 07:04:49.205000",
      "name": "name of test suite",
      "result": "FAIL",
      "start_time": "2014-09-15 06:53:36.976000",
//Should deserialize to type "List<Subtest>"
      "subtests": [
        {
          "description": "Description of Data",
          "host": "123456",
          "last_time": "2014-09-15 06:53:40.440000",
          "name": "testname.py",
          "result": "FAIL",
          "start_time": "2014-09-15 06:53:36.976000",
          "version": "2.014.09.15"
        },
        {
          "description": "Test Description",
          "host": "123456",
          "last_time": "2014-09-15 06:54:34.905000",
          "name": "testname.py",
          "result": "PASS",
          "start_time": "2014-09-15 06:54:34.827000",
          "version": "2.014.09.15"
        },
        {
          "host": "123456",
          "last_time": "2014-09-15 06:55:01.156000",
          "name": "testname.py",
          "result": "FAIL",
          "start_time": "2014-09-15 06:55:01.156000",
          "version": "2.014.09.15"
        },

      ],
      "version": "1.45"
    }
  ],
  "version": "1.23"
}
```

Example (CODE):

```
public class Base{
    public string host { get; set; }
    public DateTime last_time { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
    public string serial { get; set; }
    public DateTime start_time { get; set; }
    public List<Subtest> subtests { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
}

public class Subtest {
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public JObject Data { get; set; } // CHECK

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; } // CHECK

    [JsonProperty("host")]
    public string Host { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("info")]
    public List<StatusDetails> Info { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_time")]
    public DateTime LastRunTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string TestName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public string SubtestRunResult { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("start_time")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("trace")]
    public List<object> Trace { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The reason why JSON is lighter than XML is because it omits object types (ie tag elements in XML). I don't know how to help with this exact answer, but this may be one of the rare scenarios where you want to consider a more complete - and complex - serialization method.

Comment: Do `Base` and `Subtest` share a common base type? Otherwise you're going to get back a `List<object>` which won't be very helpful.

Comment: I deserialize the entire file to type Base, where the subtests object is deserialized to a List<Subtest>. Within that, the array could contain "Base" again OR "Subtest". I just need to figure out a way to determine whether or not to deserialize to the base class (if it contains a test suite) or to Subtest (if it IS a subtest). I don't control the data coming in, so I can't serialize it.

Comment: Right so if your list can contain two types (`Subtest` and `Base`), that property can't be a `List<Subtest>`. It has to be `List<object>` or `List<SomeBaseTypeThatBothInheritFrom>` to contain both types.

Comment: And that's fine, but how do I determine that the list of object should deserialize to "Base" OR "Subtest" once I have it deserialized as an object? Just run a foreach on the object and check if "subtests" is a key?

Comment: @LeviFuller Does it have to support polymorphism? Try these flat classess generated by http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Yes, it does. Underneath the "Subtests" node, it could contain a subtest or another "test suite" (Base class again) and I have no way of knowing.

Comment: @LeviFuller I still don't understand. what is wrong in creating a class which contains all possible properties of `base` class and `Subtest`, instead of using polymorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rework your classes to form a hierarchy. I'm probably missing a properties here, but you get the picture. The important bit is the converter.

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    public string Host { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_time")]
    public DateTime LastTime { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("start_time")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public class TestSuite : TestBase
{
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public List<TestBase> Subtests { get; set; }
}

public class Subtest : TestBase
{
    public JObject Data { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you need a custom converter to choose the correct type based on the existence of the `subtests` property:

```
public class TestBaseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader);

        TestBase result = null;

        if (obj["subtests"] != null)
        {
            result = new TestSuite();
        }
        else 
        {
            result = new Subtest();
        }

        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), result);

        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(TestBase).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
TestSuite suite = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestSuite>(
    json, new TestBaseConverter());
```

Comment: Didn't see this while I was typing my answer. Let me give it a try since it seems like a much better solution. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: @LeviFuller: Sure, let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Very impressed with your code. Tried it out and it iterates through all the way to the last `Subtest` but when it tries to step out (Calls `Populate()`on the 24th iteration at the end), it crashes. At this point in time, the result is a `TestSuite` but it thinks it needs to be a `Subtest`. Any ideas? http://snag.gy/pouum.jpg

Comment: Does it successfully deserialize any other `TestSuite` objects? Do `TestSuite` and `Subtest` have a common base class like above? The error makes me think that you have a `List<Subtest>` instead of a `List<TestBase>`

Comment: Andrew, I bow to thee in awe. Hope to be on your level some day. You were 100% correct, forgot to change the type from Subtest to TestBase.... +10000 props to you.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was adding a `List<Subtest>` property to my `Subtest` class and checked for a null value in a recursive `foreach` loop function. Not as pretty as I'd like it to be, but better than parsing it down and deserializing each `subtest` object individually.

```
private static void GetSubtest(List<Subtest> subtestList) {
        foreach (var subtest in subtestList) {
            if (subtest.Subtests != null) {
                GetSubtest(subtest.Subtests);
            }
            else {
                // add data to Vertica cluster
            }
        }
    }
```

Long day, really appreciate all you guys trying to help. New to JSON so I just couldn't get my head around it. Hopefully this helps someone else out in the future. Just throw a comment on here if you need more of an explanation.

Comment: Checking for null for different object types is pretty standard, so I don't think anyone would be shocked to see how you handled it. I discovered the same thing a few weeks ago myself! It's even worse when you don't have control of the data model.