# Newtonsoft.Json: How can I map specific properties?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Imagine I have a class like this one:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JSonProperty("a")]
    public int a;

    [JSonProperty("b")]
    public int b;

    public List<Foo> foos;
}
```

and imagine I have a Json like this one:

```
{
"a": "0",
"b": "1",
"moreFoos": {
    "total" : "2",
    "foos" : [
        {
            "a" : "2",
            "b" : "3"
        }, 
        {
            "a" : "4",
            "b" : "5"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

So, what I want to do is to deserialize with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Foo) all properties, but right now only "a" and "b" are deserialized. I have tried to put something like this on foos property:

```
[JsonProperty("moreFoos.foos")]
public List<Foo> foos;
```

but it does not work, foos is null. Do you know if there is a way to map properties dynamically this way? Of course, I would like to avoid creating a new class with an int property called "total" and another one called foos as a List of Foo objects.

Regards,
Román.

Comment: I can only think of using dynamic here: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Foo) and then using a method to convert dynamic to your object.  Otherwise you could use a [custom deserializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897199/deserialize-dynamic-json-file-c-sharp-newtonsoft-json?rq=1)

Comment: IMO, you should create a type that directly maps to the shape of your json data.  If you then would prefer a different shape, create a  new type for that and map accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to serialize the list in a private nested proxy type, like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    struct ListWrapper<T>
    {
        public int total { get { return (foos == null ? 0 : foos.Count); } }

        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling=DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<T> foos { get; set; }

        public ListWrapper(List<T> list) : this()
        {
            this.foos = list;
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("a")]
    public int a;

    [JsonProperty("b")]
    public int b;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Foo> foos;

    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    ListWrapper<Foo>? moreFoos
    {
        get
        {
            return foos == null ? null : (ListWrapper<Foo>?)new ListWrapper<Foo>(foos);
        }
        set
        {
            foos = (value == null ? null : value.Value.foos);
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm using a wrapper struct instead of a class to avoid a problem where [`ObjectCreationHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ObjectCreationHandling.htm) is set to [Reuse](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ObjectCreationHandling.htm), in which the proxy wrapper class is never set back after being gotten and filled in.)

Another option would be to use a [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to dynamically restructure your data, along the lines of [Can I serialize nested properties to my class in one operation with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30175911/3744182), but tweaked because your class is recursive.